# найти наименьшее произведение пары чисел, кратное 46, числа в которой находятся на расстоянии не больше 7 (разность в индексах ≤ 7)

Tags: python

Имеется набор данных, состоящий из положительных целых чисел, все числа не превышают 10000. Количество чисел известно, но может быть очень велико. Необходимо найти наименьшее произведение пары чисел, кратное 46, числа в которой находятся на расстоянии не больше 7 (разность в индексах ≤ 7). Под парой подразумеваются два числа, расположенных на разных местах в наборе, порядок в паре неважен. Программа должна напечатать одно число - минимально возможное произведение, соответствующее условиям задачи. Если такое произведение получить невозможно, вывести -1.

Описание входных и выходных данных

Даны два входных файла, каждый из которых содержит в первой строке количество чисел N (8 ≤ N ≤ 100000). В каждой из последующих N строк записано одно натуральное число, не превышающее 10000.

**Моё решение:**

```
f = open("27Б.txt")
n = int(f.readline())
mas = []
min_46 = 99**99
min_46_2 = 99**99
min_23 = 99**99
min_2 = 99**99
minimum_all = 99**99
for i in range(n):
    mas.append(int(f.readline()))

for j in range(n):
    if mas[j] % 23 == 0 and mas[j] % 2 == 0:
        if min_46 > mas[j] and min_46_2 < mas[j]:
            min_46 = mas[j]
        elif mas[j] < min_46 and mas[j] < min_46_2:
            min_46 = min_46_2 = mas[j]
    elif mas[j] % 23 == 0:
        if min_23 > mas[j]:
            min_23 = mas[j]
    elif mas[j] % 2 == 0:
        if min_2 > mas[j]:
            min_2 = mas[j]
    elif minimum_all > mas[j]:
        minimum_all = mas[j]

a = min(min_46*min_46_2,min_2*min_23,min_2*min_46_2,min_23*min_46_2,
        min_46*minimum_all,min_46_2*minimum_all)

if a > 99**99:
    print(-1)
else:
    print(a)
```

**Проблема:**
Не знаю как добавить условие из задачи " числа в которой находятся на расстоянии не больше 7 (разность в индексах ≤ 7)".

Comment: У вашего алгоритма квадратичная сложность, пробуйте решать задачу за линию

Comment: По-моему, решение очевидное. Если произведение делится на 46, то либо одно из чисел делится на 46, либо одно чётное, а второе делится на 23. Так что по мере ввода сортируем числа на 3 кучки, и потом сравниваем произведение наименьшего из "23" и наименьшего из "2" и произведение наименьшего из "46" с наименьшим вообще.

Comment: @Akina вы полностью правы! Только я не понимаю, как поставить условие "которой находятся на расстоянии не больше 7 (разность в индексах ≤ 7)."

Comment: Значит, при парсинге сохранять позицию элемента, дропать излишне "старые" элементы из групп, сохранять текущее минимальное произведение.

Comment: @Akina сделал новое решение по вашему способу(изменил существующее решение), но всё равно не могу понять, как добавить условие на расстоянии не больше 7

Comment: Берёшь элемент номер N - выбрасывай из групп элементы с номером N-8 и меньше, а потом смотри произведения и сравнивай с текущим минимальным. Всё.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариант решения "в лоб". Вероятно не самый эффективный, но может натолкнет на верное решение:

```
min_m = []
for i in range(len(n)):
    for j in n[i+1:i+8]:
        m = n[i]*j
        if m%46==0:
            min_m.append(m)
if len(min_m)==0:
    res_m = -1
else:
    res_m = min(min_m)
print(res_m)
```

эту часть:

```
if len(min_m)==0:
    res_m = -1
else:
    res_m = min(min_m)
```

можно заменить на:

```
res_m = min(min_m, default=-1)
```